# Can you create a pie chart with varying slice sizes in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, wolfram-language

I'm trying to make something like Wolfram's SectorChart in d3 (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/SectorChart.en/O_5.png). I'm currently using a basic data set of

```
[ { label:0, radius:1 }, { label:1, radius:1 }, { label:2, radius:2 }];
```

and I'm trying to vary the outer radius of the arc with the following function

```
var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(function(d) { return d.radius * 100; })
```

But this is not functional. Is it even possible to do this in d3? If so, am I on the right path? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can

what you are missing is, that you can't access directly `d.radius` because  pie layout is applied to the data, which wraps old data to the `data` property, so your code should be like this

```
var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(function(d) { return d.data.radius * 100; })
```

fiddle

```js
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(function (d,i) { 
      return d.data.radius*100
  });
  
  
  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.radius; });
    
 var svg =  d3.select('#result').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',500)
 
 svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie([{ label:0, radius:1 }, { label:1, radius:1 }, { label:2, radius:2 }]))
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d',arc)
    .attr('transform','translate(250,250)')
    .attr('fill','yellow')
    .attr('stroke','black')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey man! just a follow up to your comment, how can we add stroke only to the perimeter of the shape? (or remove the inner strokes)

Answer (score 1):

Will [this Aster Plot](http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1) work for you?