# JQuery Pie-chart, but unusual

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart

I'm new in `js` and `jquery` and all pie-charts that a saw looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGy9.png).

[image: this]

But I need a special one, take a look: https://yadi.sk/d/mzlKZ75iXys_hw .
It's a Life Balance Wheel. It has pieces of the same `width` but different `height`, and I have no idea how to make it!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you create a pie chart with varying slice sizes in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166584/can-you-create-a-pie-chart-with-varying-slice-sizes-in-d3)

Comment: Depends on which pie chart library you're using.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166584/can-you-create-a-pie-chart-with-varying-slice-sizes-in-d3) an answer using [tag:d3]

Comment: @freedomn-m Using only jquery, not d3

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You might also find [help/on-topic](what's on topic) useful.   jquery is not a charting library.  It's unlikely an SO user will provide you a complete pie-chart solution, without using a third-party library